# have fun(,) knowing

Tags: usage, commas

> "There was no way I could have fun knowing my phone was stolen"
>
> (The source: https://youtu.be/zRwk-yxoldc?t=82)

Is it better to put a comma after *fun*? Or is *have fun knowing something* a set usage, just like *have problem + Verb-ing*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind you didn't have fun because your phone had been stolen.

Let's put it this way: Because you knew your phone had been stolen, there was no way you could have fun - which stands for its literal meaning, but your clause with *"knowing"* idiomatically implies *"considering, or taking into considering" - expressing cause*. It is not the same as saying: It was fun having my phone stolen.

Therefore, there should be a comma separating the two clauses.

> Knowing my phone *had been* stolen, there was no way I could have fun.

Comment: But does "_There was no way I could have fun, knowing my phone was stolen_" work too?

Comment: Yes sure. I said you have to add a comma

Comment: An off-topic question, does "_It was fun having my phone stolen_" sound very weird?

Comment: Yes - but" It wasn't fun having my phone stolen" is not weird

Comment: I've asked too many questions. This'll be the last one, does "_It wasn't fun having my phone stolen_" mean the same as "_Having my phone stolen wasn't fun_"? Thank you.

Comment: Sure. It's a matter of style!

Comment: Thank you. You helped me a lot.